# Converter diversos nós em XML para struct

Tags: golang

Procurei alguns exemplos na documentação oficial do `golang` e em alguns tutoriais online porém só encontro exemplos simples vejam:

```
<data>
    <person>
        <firstname>Nic</firstname>
        <lastname>Raboy</lastname>
        <address>
            <city>San Francisco</city>
            <state>CA</state>
        </address>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstname>Maria</firstname>
        <lastname>Raboy</lastname>
    </person>
</data>
```

Para lêr esta estrutura `xml` eu só preciso de 2 `struct` sendo elas: `data` e `person`, este exemplo foi retirado deste site junto com a resolução: [thepolyglotdeveloper](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/03/parse-xml-data-in-a-golang-application/)

Structs:

```
type Data struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name `xml:"data" json:"-"`
    PersonList []Person `xml:"person" json:"people"`
}

type Person struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"person" json:"-"`
    Firstname string   `xml:"firstname" json:"firstname"`
    Lastname  string   `xml:"lastname" json:"lastname"`
    Address   *Address `xml:"address" json:"address,omitempty"`
}

type Address struct {
    City  string `xml:"city" json:"city,omitempty"`
    State string `xml:"state" json:"state,omitempty"`
}
```

Minha dúvida é como vou fazer quando um `xml` tiver mais de um nó como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<SuccessResponse>
    <Head>
        <RequestId/>
        <RequestAction>XPTP</RequestAction>
        <ResponseType>XPTU</ResponseType>
        <Timestamp>TIMESTAMP</Timestamp>
    </Head>
    <Body>
        <Products>
            <Product>...</Product>
            <Product>...</Product>
        </Products>
    </Body>
</SuccessResponse>
```

Eu vou precisar criar uma `struct` para `SuccessResponse` e dentro dela preciso ter outa `struct` com o nome `Body` e dentro de `Body` `Products` e assim por diante?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, você deve criar as estruturas aninhadas da mesma forma que o documento original. No exemplo que você deu, isso já acontece em um único nível com `Person` e `Address`.

O que pode te facilitar é acessar os campos específicos que você quer na estrutura mais interna e puxá-los mais para fora. Seguindo o exemplo que você pegou, imagine que `city` seja uma estrutura composta pelo nome da cidade, estado e país:

```
<data>
    <person>
        <firstname>Nic</firstname>
        <lastname>Raboy</lastname>
        <address>
            <city>
                <name>San Francisco</name>
                <country>USA</country>
                <state>CA</state>
            </city>
        </address>
    </person>
    <person>
        <firstname>Maria</firstname>
        <lastname>Raboy</lastname>
    </person>
</data>
```

E suponha que você só esteja interessado no nome da cidade e no do país.

É possível construir a seguinte estrutura:

```
Person struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"person" json:"-"`
    Firstname string   `xml:"firstname" json:"firstname"`
    Lastname  string   `xml:"lastname" json:"lastname"`
    City      string   `xml:"address>city>name" json:"city,omitempty"`
    Country   string   `xml:"address>city>country" json:"country,omitempty"`
}
```

<kbd>[Veja no Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/70UTB7UlAsl)</kbd>

Comment: o que é o `XMLName   xml.Name \`xml:"person" json:"-"\`` na primeira linha de `Person`?